# How to fix image not showing on recycler view using image array?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have created `recyclerView` on fragment with data on `arrays.xml` and I have one problem, image not showing in my `recyclerView`. I think its a problem in fragment but I am not sure.

This is my `distroData.java`

```
private final String mTitle;
private final String mDescription;
private final String mWeb;
private final int mThumbnail;

public DistroData (String title, String description, String web, int thumbnail){
    mTitle = title;
    mDescription = description;
    mWeb = web;
    mThumbnail = thumbnail;
}

public String getWeb(){
    return mWeb;
}

public int getThumbnail(){
    return mThumbnail;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return mTitle;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return mDescription;
}
```

}

and this is my fragment :

```
private void getDatas(){
    mGetDatas = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(){
        List<PerintahLinuxData> datas;
        String[] titles;
        String[] descriptions;
        int[] thumbnails;

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            datas = new ArrayList<>();
            titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.p_title);
            descriptions = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.p_desc);
            thumbnails = getActivity().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.p_thumbnail);
        }
```

and this is my adapter :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.title.setText(mDatas.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.description.setText(mDatas.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(mDatas.get(position).getThumbnail());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show to us adapter updating method but I can only guess that you forgot to use `notifyDataSetChange()` method on your adapter after load data.

Answer (score 0):

use this line because you put it image array into thumbnaile.

```
    holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(thumbnails.get(position).getThumbnail());
```